# Scanning Error during Import of Maven Projects into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have looked up the following error in numerous places but can't seem to get a consensus on the solution or one that works for that matter.

"Maven Projects
Scanning error[path to project]; java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"

I set MAVEN_OPTS to "-Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024"

The project I am importing is an assets project with many images, icons, .swf, and JS files.

Is there something else I need or am I setting the above in the terminal the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the maven build process in jvisualvm (from your jdk). There you can see how much memory is consumed. If you see that the build exceeds the 1024 MB, set -Xmx to a higher value. If you see that the maximal heap size is below 1024 MB, then your MAVEN_OPTS settings did not work.

Comment: I will need to research jvisualvm it seems as I am unfamiliar with that.

Comment: Installed Jvisualvm but after a couple of hours, still not sure how to launch/use it. Nice strategy you provided but definitely a long cut.

Comment: Ok , I finally got that installed and running AFTER I INSTALLED THE NEWEST JDK. I am watching the Heap size for Eclipse max out at 536B and when the used heap size gets to 527B it errors out. So it appears that the Xmx is at 512? I am typing "export MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx1024m " in terminal. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Changed the memory in Eclipse.ini. No longer get that error now that I have 1024B but now I am getting a java.lan.StackOverflowError. On to the next problem...

Comment: Sorry, I could not comment earlier. I am surprised that you did not find jvisualvm. It is part of the jdk and lies in the directory /Java/jdk1.8.0_92/bin/

Comment: In order for me to find it, I need to know to look there ;) Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

- Increase more heap size more again, Setting for JVM: http://www.wikihow.com/Increase-Java-Memory-in-Windows-7
- Open Java mission control to see RAM, heap size usage. It will give you insight to good decision how much memory size is suitable.
  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/mission-control/java-mission-control-1998576.html